# AccessViolation C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I'm making a C++/CLI wrapper to a native 3rd party library as the code follows:

```
#pragma once
#include <Codegen.h>
#include <string>
using namespace System;

namespace CodegenWrapper {

    public ref class CodegenWrapper
    {
    private:
        Codegen * codegen;
    public:     
        CodegenWrapper(array<float>^ pcm, uint numSamples, int start_offset)
        {   
            float* audio = new float[pcm->Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pcm->Length; i++)
            {
                audio[i] = (float)pcm[i];
            }
            codegen = new Codegen(audio,numSamples,start_offset);
        }

        String^ GetCodeString(){ return  gcnew String(codegen->getCodeString().c_str());}


        int GetNumCodes(){return codegen->getNumCodes();}

        float GetVersion() { return codegen->getVersion(); }

        ~CodegenWrapper(){delete codegen;}
    };
}
```

This is the exception even after does the changes to Dispose:

```
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=CodegenWrapper
  StackTrace:
       at delete(Void* )
       at std.basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >._Tidy(basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* , Boolean _Built, UInt32 _Newsize) in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xmemory0:line 588
       at CodegenWrapper.CodegenWrapper.GetCodeString() in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xstring:line 962
       at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\galvesribeiro\Desktop\Econest\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 47
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I'm getting Access Violation when calling GetCodeString().

What should be the problem?

Comment: We cannot see what getNumCodes(); does.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, this may well happen in the native code.  Your wrapper is however imperfect.  You are not properly protecting against the client code disposing the wrapper too soon.  One misplaced *using* statement is enough to trip an AccessViolation.  You are also forgetting the finalizer, required to avoid a permanent leak when the client code forgets to dispose.  Make it look like this:

```
    ~CodegenWrapper() {
        delete codegen;
        codegen = 0;
    }

    !CodegenWrapper() {
        delete codegen;
    }

    int GetNumCodes() {
        if (!codegen) throw gcnew ObjectDisposedException("CodegenWrapper");
        return codegen->getNumCodes();
    }
```

Add the disposed test to the other members as well.

Comment: Dpnt fixed the problem Hans. Also, I edited with full stack of the exception details. Thanks anyway

Comment: Best to use a smart pointer instead of manually managing resources.

Comment: It is falling over on deleting an std::string.  Not otherwise visible in the snippet.  Heap corruption is by far the most common reason for native code failure.  Well, at least you got a good wrapper out of this answer :)

Comment: Ben / Hans I'm totally noob on C++/CLI, can you provide me code sample on how to make this thing really work? Thanks a lot! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Anyone comes with a solution for this problem?